# Product filtering like shopping sites

Tags: php, sql

I want to make a filter for my products like we do in shopping sites as like for prices, type etc.

Code i am using:

```
if($_GET['fname']  == "") {
  $url = "try5.php?fname=".$_POST['getme'];
  header("Location:$url");
}
else {
  $url = "try5.php?fname=".$_GET['fname'].",".$_POST['getme'];
  header("Location:$url");
}
```

And also want to be that item selected by getting its name from url, but didint get good results.

Comment: To be honest I have no idea what your code have to do what you are trying to do

Comment: I ws trying to do, is, i have a list of checkbox with diff pro name, and want to make a filter if i select one item my page echo all items from sql of that same selected item, if i select two items, my page display two items data from SQl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That'll have to be done in your SQL.

```
if(isset($_POST['getme']))
{
    $item_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['getme']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE `itemname`='$item_name';";
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code doesn't do anything related to filtering and such. to filter the products you'll have to fetch them from your `database` and do a query to filter them for an example

```
$query = "select * from mytable order by HERE IS YOUR FILTERING GOES";
```

above code is just an example that show you the way to what you want.